# Why ODBC driver needs to be installed in OS

Tags: database, odbc

I don't understand why ODBC requires installation of a driver on a OS level. When I create an application that wants to connect with database, from my understanding, I should just get appropriate library for the programming language that I'm using. What is so special about ODBC that it needs to be installed seperately?

Comment: ODBC is just an abstraction layer for a database access. It allows working with various databases in a uniform way. Of course, databases differ a lot from each other so ODBC implements some common DB features only and to use others you should write more code. Once ODBC provides access to very different databases (Oracle, MS SQL Server, Firebird, PostgreSQL, etc.) you have to install drivers for databases you want to access to. OS cannot have installed ODBC drivers for all databases in the world.

Comment: @oleque Sure, but, for example, when I want to access CosmosDB, or use Entity Framework to access SQL Server, I just download the library for it - I do not install anything on my host PC. That's why I wonder about ODBC and its requirement of having a driver in OS. I'm not a fan of installing too many things, because operating systems become messy after.

Comment: I think the library you wrote about is just a kind of "driver" for your database. ODBC is old enough technology so it requires for some libraries to be installed on your PC, moreover it is commonly managed via system registry (ODBC drivers and DSNs are registered in system registry to be available for every program on the PC). Also ODBC allows file DSNs and DSN-less connections but it seems the common way is using registry DSNs (I'm not sure here it is just my experience).

Comment: Yes, the library is a kind of driver. Still, I do not like the idea of actually modifying your environment (by installation of additional software, which changes Windows registry, adds some files, only God knows where, etc.)